# "It worths it", "it worth it" or "it is worth it"?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why?

I think "worth it" is an adjective phrase. So what is "worth" then?

Example:

> You should try spending money on her. **It worths it**.
>
> You should try spending money on her. **It worth it**.
>
> You should try spending money on her. **It is worth it**.

Which one is right? The last 2 are not condemned by grammar checker.

Comment: Please give us some more context. How is the phrase being used (in a complete sentence)? I believe *worths* is a word only in the fact that it's the plural of the noun *worth*.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

*Worth* as a verb is obsolete. Where have you seen or heard *It worths it* or *It worth it*?

What you will find is *It’s worth it*, used to describe something that has a value equivalent to what is being asked for it either in terms of money or effort. In that use, *worth* is an adjective.

Comment: I see. Worth it is an adjective phrase. What is "worth" by itself then? Combined with it, it becomes an adjective.

Comment: I think it's worth it sounds a lot like it worth it. I think that's where the confusion is.

Comment: 'Worth' can be both an adjective and a noun.

Comment: this stuff worths $6000?

Comment: No, you can't say that.

Comment: And how would you say that?

Comment: You'd say that: `This stuff is worth $6000`

Comment: Why does it have the word "it" in the end? Can I just say "It is worth"?

Answer (score 36):

Only the last one is correct.

"Worth" is classified as an Adjective and used as one. (Although it also acts differently from all of the Adjectives.)

In your particular example, "worth" is used as an Adjective but acts as a Preposition. That's why it's normally followed by a Noun, a Pronoun or a Gerund.

Ex.

It's worth a try.

It's worth it.

It's worth trying.

Comment: You say::: "worth" is used as an Adjective but acts as a Preposition. That's why it's normally followed by a Noun, a Pronoun or a Gerund.<<< Please give an example of worth used as an adjective followed by a noun? Sure it is an adj, but my OED says "not before by a noun". I hope this comment is worthy of the space here, worthwhile?!!

Answer (score 0):

What you will find is worth it, used to describe something that has a value equivalent to what is being asked for it either in terms of money or effort. In that use, worth is an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble understanding this, then look at 'worth' as 'having value.'
then:
It's worth a try.
is equivalent to (but NOT replaceable by)
It has value to try OR There is value in trying

It's worth it.
is equivalent to (but NOT replaceable by)
It has value (roughly equivalent value).

It's worth trying.
is equivalent to (but NOT replaceable by)
It has value to try OR there is value in trying

Answer (score 0):

The question is worthy of an answer. Is it an adjective, then it should have a noun following. It is suggested it could be used as a verb. English language does evolve in that direction. Would >>The question worths a response<< work? Worths=merits? Eccentric but could pass with a [sic]. The spell-check has lighted up. Grammar-check?

Answer (score -1):

"It doesn't worth it." is very common.

So as, "It worths every penny of it.", do you agree?

"It's worth it" sounds very very strange.

Why can't we simply use worth as a verb? Just keep it simple.

Comment: Not only is it certainly **not** “very common”, there is simply no such thing as “It doesn’t worth it.” This is a made-up answer claiming something that does not exist does. *Worth* is no longer a verb. It is a very strange word, I admit, in that it appears to be an adjective that takes an object complement, or perhaps some bizarre form of preposition. But whatever it is, it is not a verb.

Comment: @rockyliu - This sounds strange even to me, a non-native English speaker :)